# Attribute of a XML line

Tags: java, xml

I have the following code in Java and I want to extract the '01' (segment id) from a XML file

I use the `eElement.getElementsByTagName("height").item(0).getTextContent()` to extract the height,slope,length,rrc,... but I cant extract the id and I tried the function `getAttribute`

Here is my Java code

```
 NodeList listSegment = doc.getElementsByTagName("segment_list");
 for (int count = 0; count< listSegment.getLength(); count++) {
      Node nodeSegment = listSegment.item(count);
      if (nodeSegment.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element eElement = (Element) nodeSegment;
          System.out.println("Segment id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
          System.out.println("height : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("height").item(0).getTextContent().replaceAll("\"", ""));
      }
}
```

And here is the sample of my XML code

```
<segment_list>
  <segment id="01">
    <height>100</height>
    <slope>0</slope>
    <length>10 Km</length>
    <rrc>0.01</rrc>
    <max_velocity>90 Km/h</max_velocity>
    <min_velocity>0 Km/h</min_velocity>
    <number_vehicles>30</number_vehicles>
  </segment>
</segment_list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the good methods, but not with good parameters

because your attribute is one of segment, you have to select segment tags, and not segment_list tags

```
NodeList listSegment = doc.getElementsByTagName("segment");
```

To get this attribute, this is ok:

```
    String id = element.getAttribute("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

In `DOM` node is unit of every matter. i.e. `ELEMENT` and `ATTRIBUTE` are different nodes. When you use `doc.getElementByTagName` you will only get element, not attributes.

You will have to get parent element.

Here is an example to help you.

```
 String sml ="<segment_list>"
           + "    <segment id=\"01\">"
           + "        <height>100</height>"
           + "        <slope>0</slope>"
           + "        <length>10 Km</length>"
           + "        <rrc>0.01</rrc>"
           + "        <max_velocity>90 Km/h</max_velocity>"
           + "        <min_velocity>0 Km/h</min_velocity>"
           + "        <number_vehicles>30</number_vehicles>"
           + "     </segment>"
           + "</segment_list>";
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 NodeList listSegment = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())).getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();//.getElementsByTagName("segment_list");
 for (int count = 0; count< listSegment.getLength(); count++) {

     Node nodeSegment = listSegment.item(count);
     System.out.println("key: " + nodeSegment.getNodeName());
     System.out.println("value: " + nodeSegment.getNodeValue());
     NamedNodeMap attr = nodeSegment.getAttributes();
     for(int j = 0; j < attr.getLength(); j++){
         System.out.println("akey: " + attr.item(j).getNodeName());
         System.out.println("aval: " + attr.item(j).getNodeValue());
     }
 }
```

**Output :**

```
key: segment
value: null
akey: id
aval: 01
```

Another thing is don't exclude attribute by using `if (nodeSegment.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)` condition.